# active class to elements one by one with basic js

Tags: javascript

i need to "move" active class one by one to this 5 div elements but with very basic js because still learning basics, i found this solution and it work but i want transform this in a for loop,it is possible without any function,foreach loop,only with very basics? thanks

this is my solution:

```
next.addEventListener('click', function(){

    let current = document.querySelector('.active')

    if(current.classList.contains('active')){
        imgItems[1].classList.add('active')
        imgItems[0].classList.remove('active')
    }

    if (current.classList.contains('active')) {
        imgItems[1].classList.remove('active')
        imgItems[2].classList.add('active')
    }
    if (current.classList.contains('active')) {
        imgItems[2].classList.remove('active')
        imgItems[3].classList.add('active')
    }
    if (current.classList.contains('active')) {
        imgItems[3].classList.remove('active')
        imgItems[4].classList.add('active')
    }
    

})
```

I try many times and online solutions is nice but too advanced for me,i have learning only array and cycle.

Comment: There's no iteration in OP code. It's an eventListener with a series of badly written flow control statements, so nothing is reiterated.

Comment: @zer00ne while it's not the best code, it does what op intended. It doesn't roll back over but it does change the active element In sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the items are adjacent in the DOM, you can use `nextElementSibling` to go to the next item.

```js
const next = document.getElementById("next");

next.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let current = document.querySelector(".active");
  let nextItem = current.nextElementSibling;
  if (!nextItem) {
    // Go back to the first item
    nextItem = document.querySelector(".item");
  }
  current.classList.remove("active");
  nextItem.classList.add("active");
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item active">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
</div>

<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let current = document.querySelector('.active');
    for (let index = 0; index <= 3; index++) {
        if (current.classList.contains('active')) {
            imgItems[index].classList.remove('active');
            imgItems[index + 1].classList.add('active');
        }
    }
});
```

Javascript has no foreach loop. It has for .. in loop, for .. of loop and normal C-style loop. In this case I have used the latter because we are to work with indexes.

It seems that you intend to cascade the `active` class towards the end of some `imgItems` set, so the idea is to loop an `index` from 0 up to 3 and each time to check whether `current` has an `active` class, then remove that class from the actual element on the index we are currently on and add this class to the next. You can also do it without a loop, like this:

```js
let imgItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('div')];
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener('click', function() {
    let current = document.querySelector('.active');
    let index = imgItems.indexOf(current);
    if (index < imgItems.length - 1) {
        imgItems[index].classList.remove('active');
        imgItems[index + 1].classList.add('active');
    } else {
        alert('You are at the last item');
    }
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}

div.active {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="active"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<input type="button" value="next" id="next">
```

Basically we convert the array-like object called `imgItems` to an array using the spread operator (the [...] part) and inside the event, you get the index of current in the array and if it's not the very last one, you remove the active class and add it to the next.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach that's a little more developed – and *not* necessarily the "*very basic*" approach you requested – which allows for presses of a `<button>` to navigate through a list of elements; explanatory comments are in the code in order that you, and others, might learn from it:

```js
// defining a named function - navigation() - that takes
// one argument, a reference to the Event to which this
// function is bound; this is passed automatically from
// the later use of EventTarget.addEventListener():
const navigation = function(evt) {
  // here we use destructuring assignment to retrieve
  // the currentTarget property from the evt Object,
  // creating a variable of that same name; the
  // currentTarget is the element node to which the
  // event-handler (this function) is bound:
  let {
    currentTarget
  } = evt;
  // we navigate from the currentTarget element to its closest
  // ancestor element that has a "data-active-class" attribute,
  // and from that element we use the HTMLElement.dataset API
  // to retrieve the attribute-value for the "data-active-class"
  // attribute, note that we're also using camelCase notation:
  let activeClassName = currentTarget.closest("[data-active-class]").dataset.activeClass;
  // retrieve the attribute-value of the "data-role" attribute
  // from the currentTarget element, and convert that string
  // to its lower-case equivalent:
  let direction = currentTarget.dataset.role.toLowerCase();
  // as above, we navigate from the currentTarget to its closest
  // ancestor with a "data-iterates" attribute, and then retrieving
  // the attribute-value:
  let selector = currentTarget.closest("[data-iterates]").dataset.iterates;
  // here we use document.querySelectorAll() to find all elements
  // within the document that match the supplied selector (retrieved
  // previously), and convert that NodeList into an Array, using
  // Array.from():
  let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  // using Array.prototype.map() to create a new Array based
  // on the elements Array:
  let currentState = elements.map(
    // these arguments are available automatically to the
    // Array method; the names are entirely user-defined
    // while the relevant arguments are always in this order:
    //  el, a reference to the current Node of the Array of Nodes,
    //  index, the index of the current Array-element in the Array,
    // all, a reference to the current Array over which we're iterating:
    function(el, index, all) {
      // from the Array method we return an Object (creating an
      // Array of Objects derived from the current Array of Nodes):
      return {
        // here we return the named property, and property-values
        // in the form of:
        //      el: el,
        //      index: index
        // taking advantage of the shorthand notation:
        el,
        index,
        // here we return an isActive property with its value
        // a Boolean true/false, according to whether the current
        // element node has a class-name matching the activeClassName
        // value (retrieved above):
        isActive: el.classList.contains(activeClassName),
        // returning a 'progress' property with its value another Object:
        progress: {
          // next: using a conditional (ternary) operator, if the assessment
          // - is index + 1 equal to the length of the whole Array - is true/truthy
          // we return first Array-element, otherwise we return the Array-element
          // at the next index:
          next: (
            (index + 1) === all.length ? all.at(0) : all.at(index + 1)
          ),
          // if index - 1 is less than zero, we return the last Array-element
          // using Array.prototype.at() and an index of -1; otherwise we
          // return the previous Array-element:
          previous: (
            (index - 1) < 0 ? all.at(-1) : all.at(index - 1)
          )
        }
      };
    });
  // we then use Array.prototype.find()
  let currentlyActive = currentState.find(
    // again, we're retrieving the arguments available to the
    // method, which is an Object in this case:
    // {...}, using destructuring assignment to retrieve the named
    // properties (as variables) of the current Array-element (the Object):
    ({
      isActive
      // and we return the Array-element for which the test evaluates to
      // a Boolean true/truthy value; the 'isActive' property is itself
      // a Boolean, and so effectively we're returning (using the implicit
      // return of an Arrow function) either true or false directly:
    }) => isActive);
  // we use destructuring assignment again, to retrieve properties from
  // the currentlyActive Object:
  let {
    // here we retrieve the named property ('el') and assign it to
    // a different variable name 'currentElement', simarly we retrieve
    // and 'index' property, and also assign a new variable name
    // 'currentIndex' so the variable-name implies what its value
    // is/represents:
    el: currentElement,
    index: currentIndex,
    progress
  } = currentlyActive;

  // here we use the Element.classList API to remove the class
  // held in the activeClassName variable:
  currentElement.classList.remove(activeClassName);
  // and here we use bracket-notation to retrieve the
  // relevant property of the progress Object, and again
  // using the Element.classList API we add the
  // activeClassName to that element:
  progress[direction].classList.add(activeClassName);
};

// using document.querySelector to find elements with a "data-role" custom
// attribute that is itself nested within an ancestor with a "data-iterates"
// custom attribute; we then use NodeList.forEach() to iterate over the
// element ndoes that were retrieved:
document.querySelectorAll("[data-iterates] [data-role]").forEach(
  // and pass in a reference to the current Node of the NodeList,
  // and use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the
  // navigation() function - note the deliberately omitted
  // parentheses; we want to bind the function itself not the
  // returned property of the function - as the event-handler
  // for the "click" event:
  (el) => el.addEventListener("click", navigation)
);
```

```css
:root {
  --spacing: 1rem;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  block-size: 100vh;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

menu,
ol,
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  inline-size: clamp(30rem, 80% + 5vmin, 1200px);
  margin-inline: auto;
  min-block-size: 100%;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

.controls {}

li a,
button {
  padding-block: calc(var(--spacing)/2);
  padding-inline: var(--spacing);
}

section {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  margin-block: var(--spacing);
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

li a {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, lime, transparent);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <!-- taking advantage of custom data-* attributes to allow the
       user to customise the JavaScript functionality:
          data-active-class: the attribute that defines the class-name
            that will be considered the indicator of the "active" element,
          data-iterates: the attribute that defines the CSS selector for
            the elements over which the JavaScript will iterate.
       -->
  <div
        class="controls"
        data-active-class="active"
        data-iterates="a">
    <!-- using the data-role attribute to define the "role" of the
         current element in the navigation through/over the
         elements: -->
    <button data-role="previous">previous</button>
    <button data-role="next">next</button>
  </div>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Link element 01</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 02</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 03</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 04</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 05</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 06</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 07</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 08</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 09</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ug6d4akp/).

Note that in the above demo, there is no error-handling for a situation in which there is no element with a class-name matching the `activeClassName`, or multiple classes matching that class-name. If such is required you'd need to either implement that yourself, or ask a question about how it might/should be handled in the event that you're unable to write such code.

The demo below shows one use of the possible customisations (bear in mind the aesthetics are horrible, as this is merely a proof-of-concept):

```js
// defining a named function - navigation() - that takes
// one argument, a reference to the Event to which this
// function is bound; this is passed automatically from
// the later use of EventTarget.addEventListener():
const navigation = function(evt) {
  // here we use destructuring assignment to retrieve
  // the currentTarget property from the evt Object,
  // creating a variable of that same name; the
  // currentTarget is the element node to which the
  // event-handler (this function) is bound:
  let {
    currentTarget
  } = evt;
  // we navigate from the currentTarget element to its closest
  // ancestor element that has a "data-active-class" attribute,
  // and from that element we use the HTMLElement.dataset API
  // to retrieve the attribute-value for the "data-active-class"
  // attribute, note that we're also using camelCase notation:
  let activeClassName = currentTarget.closest("[data-active-class]").dataset.activeClass;
  // retrieve the attribute-value of the "data-role" attribute
  // from the currentTarget element, and convert that string
  // to its lower-case equivalent:
  let direction = currentTarget.dataset.role.toLowerCase();
  // as above, we navigate from the currentTarget to its closest
  // ancestor with a "data-iterates" attribute, and then retrieving
  // the attribute-value:
  let selector = currentTarget.closest("[data-iterates]").dataset.iterates;
  // here we use document.querySelectorAll() to find all elements
  // within the document that match the supplied selector (retrieved
  // previously), and convert that NodeList into an Array, using
  // Array.from():
  let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  // using Array.prototype.map() to create a new Array based
  // on the elements Array:
  let currentState = elements.map(
    // these arguments are available automatically to the
    // Array method; the names are entirely user-defined
    // while the relevant arguments are always in this order:
    //  el, a reference to the current Node of the Array of Nodes,
    //  index, the index of the current Array-element in the Array,
    // all, a reference to the current Array over which we're iterating:
    function(el, index, all) {
      // from the Array method we return an Object (creating an
      // Array of Objects derived from the current Array of Nodes):
      return {
        // here we return the named property, and property-values
        // in the form of:
        //      el: el,
        //      index: index
        // taking advantage of the shorthand notation:
        el,
        index,
        // here we return an isActive property with its value
        // a Boolean true/false, according to whether the current
        // element node has a class-name matching the activeClassName
        // value (retrieved above):
        isActive: el.classList.contains(activeClassName),
        // returning a 'progress' property with its value another Object:
        progress: {
          // next: using a conditional (ternary) operator, if the assessment
          // - is index + 1 equal to the length of the whole Array - is true/truthy
          // we return first Array-element, otherwise we return the Array-element
          // at the next index:
          next: (
            (index + 1) === all.length ? all.at(0) : all.at(index + 1)
          ),
          // if index - 1 is less than zero, we return the last Array-element
          // using Array.prototype.at() and an index of -1; otherwise we
          // return the previous Array-element:
          previous: (
            (index - 1) < 0 ? all.at(-1) : all.at(index - 1)
          )
        }
      };
    });
  // we then use Array.prototype.find()
  let currentlyActive = currentState.find(
    // again, we're retrieving the arguments available to the
    // method, which is an Object in this case:
    // {...}, using destructuring assignment to retrieve the named
    // properties (as variables) of the current Array-element (the Object):
    ({
      isActive
      // and we return the Array-element for which the test evaluates to
      // a Boolean true/truthy value; the 'isActive' property is itself
      // a Boolean, and so effectively we're returning (using the implicit
      // return of an Arrow function) either true or false directly:
    }) => isActive);
  // we use destructuring assignment again, to retrieve properties from
  // the currentlyActive Object:
  let {
    // here we retrieve the named property ('el') and assign it to
    // a different variable name 'currentElement', simarly we retrieve
    // and 'index' property, and also assign a new variable name
    // 'currentIndex' so the variable-name implies what its value
    // is/represents:
    el: currentElement,
    index: currentIndex,
    progress
  } = currentlyActive;

  // here we use the Element.classList API to remove the class
  // held in the activeClassName variable:
  currentElement.classList.remove(activeClassName);
  // and here we use bracket-notation to retrieve the
  // relevant property of the progress Object, and again
  // using the Element.classList API we add the
  // activeClassName to that element:
  progress[direction].classList.add(activeClassName);
};

// using document.querySelector to find elements with a "data-role" custom
// attribute that is itself nested within an ancestor with a "data-iterates"
// custom attribute; we then use NodeList.forEach() to iterate over the
// element ndoes that were retrieved:
document.querySelectorAll("[data-iterates] [data-role]").forEach(
  // and pass in a reference to the current Node of the NodeList,
  // and use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the
  // navigation() function - note the deliberately omitted
  // parentheses; we want to bind the function itself not the
  // returned property of the function - as the event-handler
  // for the "click" event:
  (el) => el.addEventListener("click", navigation)
);

document.querySelectorAll('[data-iterates]').forEach(
  (el) => [...el.children].forEach(
    (k) => k.innerHTML += `: <span>${el.dataset.iterates}</span>`
  )
);
```

```css
:root {
  --spacing: 1rem;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  block-size: 100vh;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

menu,
ol,
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  inline-size: clamp(30rem, 80% + 5vmin, 1200px);
  margin-inline: auto;
  min-block-size: 100%;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

main *:not(button span) {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding-block: calc(var(--spacing)/2);
  padding-inline: var(--spacing);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.controls {
  display: inline-block;
  inline-size: 45%;
}

section {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  margin-block: var(--spacing);
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

li {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

li a {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, lime, transparent);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.special {
  border-image: radial-gradient(at 0 0, purple, aqua) 9;
}

.extraSpecialActive {
  border: 2px solid hsl(280deg 70% 50% / 1);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="controls" data-active-class="active" data-iterates="a">
    <button data-role="previous">previous</button>
    <button data-role="next">next</button>
  </div>
  <!-- all I've done here is add an extra pair of <button> elements within
       a parent element with relevant "data-active-class" and "data-iterates"
       attributes, and values (though obviously I've added the relevant class
       -names to elements in the document) -->
  <div class="controls" data-active-class="extraSpecialActive" data-iterates=".special">
    <button data-role="previous">previous</button>
    <button data-role="next">next</button>
  </div>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="special extraSpecialActive">Link element 01</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 02</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 03</a></li>
      <li>
        <span>span: 1</span>
        <span>span: 2</span>
        <span class="special">span: 3</span>
        <span>span: 4</span>
        <span class="special">span: 5</span>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 05</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Link element 06</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 07</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 08</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 09</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link element 11</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <article>
    <h3 class="special">Special heading</h3>
  </article>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ug6d4akp/1/).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at).
- [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLElement.dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).